# Is there a "ZIP project" in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, zip, project, cab

In Visual Studio there are several "Setup and Deployment" projects, one of these is "**CAB Project**".

[image: http://i55.tinypic.com/21cxaoi.png]

But I actually want a simple "ZIP Project" which enables me to add some folders + dll's from my solution and package this all in a zip file for easy distribution on the web.

- Is there such a project type ?
- When I want to create this by myself,
  what resources and references should
  I use to build this ?

**Edit**

@Cheeso
I created a dummy 'class library' project which has dependencies on all the sub projects.
In this dummy project I used the post-build event to zip the dll's using 7-zip.
But I was hoping that there was a better solution for this.

Answer (score 4):

The [MSBuild Extension Pack](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/) offers some [compression tasks](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.1.0/html/6d4a6f16-ae4d-960e-b4f9-b70c503bd0bf.htm) you could use.

For example, edit your project file, uncommenting the 'AfterBuild' target and including an appropriate compression task that packages up the content you want.

```
<Project>
  ...
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Set the collection of files to Zip-->
      <FilesToZip Include="C:\YourContent\*"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.DNZip TaskAction="Create" CompressFiles="@(FilesToZip)" ZipFileName="C:\YourZipFile.zip"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're after, a quick-and-easy solution might be to write a powershell or Javascript script, or a batch file, that runs as a post-build event.
You'll need a zip library, probably.  DotNetZip works.

Answer (score 0):

There's a (poorly marketed) feature of [DPack](http://www.usysware.com/dpack/Backup.aspx), called Solution Backup that will create a zip file of your solution from within visual studio.

It's free and painless to install.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken - providing a "404" error